# Creating Multiple Object using a loop in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

I am new in C++ and OOP. I want to create 10 objects of a class using a loop. For example , I have a class

```
class A{
//something
};

int main(){
A a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10;

}
```

Rather that writing all the object name manually I want to make a loop where every iteration will give a new object and then I can access to the class property according to my requirement.

Comment: What you want is an array, a `std::array<A, 10>`, or a `std::vector<A>`. If you know it will always be 10, use `std::array`. If you don't know how many elements beforehand, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Usually in this situation one would declare an array (e.g. `A a[9];`)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You mean `A a[10];`. There are 10 variables in the OPs example.

Comment: Yes, I do mean `a[10]`.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You can not create name for variable at the runtime,

but still you have a option to create 10 variables by using `Array` or `Vector` like given in below

`std::array<A, 10>, or a std::vector<A>`